# How get systemd status in json format?

Tags: systemd, json

I want to get service status details (Loaded, enabled, active, running, since, Main PID) in machine readable form and I know that systemd tools have `--output=json` option, but if I do:

```
 systemctl status servicename --output=json --plain
```

I see something like:

```
● snapd.service - Snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-04-16 11:20:07 MSK; 4h 45min ago
 Main PID: 738 (snapd)
    Tasks: 10 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
           └─738 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

{ "__CURSOR" : "s=461ecb6a4b814913acd57572cd1e1c82;...
```

Journal records are in JSON. But how to get the service status in JSON if it's possible?

Comment: Take a look https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/83

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple way to getting service status in machine readable form:

```
systemctl show --no-pager servicename
```

This command outputs data in `key=value` format:

```
Type=notify
Restart=always
NotifyAccess=main
...
```

If `JSON` format is required, you can use the following simple Python script (Python 2 and 3 compatible) `get_service_info.py`:

```
import os, sys, subprocess, json
key_value = subprocess.check_output(["systemctl", "show", sys.argv[1]], universal_newlines=True).split('\n')
json_dict = {}
for entry in key_value:
    kv = entry.split("=", 1)
    if len(kv) == 2:
        json_dict[kv[0]] = kv[1]
json.dump(json_dict, sys.stdout)
```

Usage:

```
get_service_info.py servicename
```

Comment: the "keys" for OPs question are `ActiveState`, `UnitFileState`, `ExecMainStartTimestamp`,`LoadState` `ExecMainPID` so  grep those then can easily get the info without need for json.  If more are need well then json.

Comment: Still want that json?  for javascript there is already an xdg parser which is what the `--no-page` outputs.  see  https://www.npmjs.com/package/xdg-parse

Comment: For xdg-parse package to work here you need to prepend `'[State]\n'` first as that parser expects sections. Then the you'll get back a `State:` prop with all keys below.   `xdgparse('[State]\n'+str).State`

Answer (score 12):

You can use `jq` for this, too:

```
systemctl show --no-page iptables \
    | jq --slurp --raw-input \
        'split("\n")
        | map(select(. != "") 
        | split("=") 
        | {"key": .[0], "value": (.[1:] | join("="))})
        | from_entries'
```

produces:

```
{
  "Type": "oneshot",
  "Restart": "no",
  "NotifyAccess": "none",
  "ExecStart": "{ path=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init ; argv[]=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start ; ignore_errors=no ; start_time=[n/a] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=0 ; code=(null) ; status=0/0 }",
  [... like 60 more entries ...],
  "CollectMode": "inactive"
}
```

Decode of `jq` command:

```
--slurp - read the whole thing as a really big string
--raw-input - p.s. it's not json input
split("\n") - break the input into an array of lines
map( ... )  - perform some transformation on each array element
select(. != "") - skip blank lines
split("=") - split the current line into array elements at each "="
(.[1:] | join("=")) - avoid mangling values with equal signs
```

(be warned: this will truncate values if the value itself contains an equals sign.  This can probably be worked around but for this purpose seems fine)

```
{"key": .[0], "value": .[1]}  - build an key/value pair object
```

(at this point `map` returns an array of key/value objects)

```
from_entries - turn an array of "key"/"value" objects into an object
```

Comment: OK, I maybe got a little nerd sniped.  To *not* mangle values that contain equals signs, replace `.[1]` with `(.[1:] | join("="))` which will grab the remainder of the array and staple it back together using equals signs.

Comment: That's a great addition to your answer, I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: This is brilliant and simple. Thanks!

Comment: That `jq` snippet deserves its own question and answer. Excellent work, @DarylBanttari

Answer (score 2):

The recommendation by the developers is to use the [dbus API](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/) for programmatic access to service status instead.  If you really need JSON, you could adapt the DBUS API to produce the JSON you need.

See the Github issue [--output json doesn't produce json output](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/83) for discussion among the developers about why the DBUS API is recommended over JSON output.

Comment: for nodejs folks https://www.npmjs.com/package/dbus-native.   Would honestly be excellent way to monitor processes on a machine.  I'll get on this in my spare time.